# how to use the SignalR in react?

Tags: reactjs, paas

how to use the SignalR in react? I'm not familiar with react, do you have any guideline?

I have tried many articles but no one help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'signalr';

class Dashboard extends Component {
   constructor(props) {    
   super(props);
   var connection = $.hubConnection('http://[address]:[port]');
   var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('[hubname]');   

    // atempt connection, and handle errors
    connection.start()
    .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); });
}

  render() {
    return (...);
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, try to check whether your client and server is using the same version of signallR library, if theres mismatch, connection won't be set.

Comment: The new SignalR client is not using jQuery as dependency any more.